# EAR - Enterprise Java bean, Servlets included application - Enterprise Java Application

Tags: jboss

I am in lookout of a Java Enterprise application that has code and features to connect different J2EE compontents like JDBC (oracle or mysql), JMS, web services etc...

Is there any test application available anywhere which showcases all features, so I can try to deploy with requirement middleware configurations... I do understand we have sample application with Jboss or any other J2EE complaint application server, but I am thinking if there anything above the sample application

Regards
G

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Oracle's Java Pet Store](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/petstore1-3-1-02-139690.html).

From the description:

> The demo shows how to use JavaServer Pages ("JSP"), Java Servlet,
>   Enterprise JavaBeans ("EJB"), and Java Message Service ("JMS")
>   technologies.

Comment: ya , thanks I have heard of that though,but not tried